# How to remove an object from an array using click events

Tags: javascript, dom, button, click, innerhtml

I am new to javascript and am in need of some assistance. I've attempted to look this up all week and can't seem to grasp the concept. I have written some code that allows me to create cards using `innerhtml()`. these cards grab all the necessary information from an array. I've made it to where the cards will be deleted once the button on said cards is clicked, however it deletes all of the cards and I need it to delete the cards individually when the buttons are clicked.. forgive my terminology and lack of understanding. here is my javascript code.

```js
console.log("HelloWorld!");
//print to dom function for innerhtml
const printToDom = (divId, textToPrint) => {
    console.log(textToPrint);
    const selectedDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
    selectedDiv.innerHTML = textToPrint
};

//this is my hogwarts array

const hogwartsHouse = [
    'Griffindor', 'Hufflepuff', 'Slytherin', 'Ravenclaw' 
];

//this variable grabs the users input into my form

const names = document.getElementById("insertName");

//this variable sets the student id to 0
//student id is located inside the sort init function

let studentId = 0;


const students = [];

//this function allows my form to be seen

function openForm() {
   x = document.getElementById("form");
   if(x.style.display === "none") {
       x.style.display = "block";
   } else {
       x.style.display = "none";
   }
};

//this function builds the card

const sortBuilder = (sortingHat) => {
    
    let domString = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < sortingHat.length; i++){
        domString +=    `<div id="cardContainer">`
        domString +=    `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">`
        domString +=        `<div class="card-body">`
        domString +=        `<h5 class="cardTitle">${sortingHat[i].name}</h5>`
        domString +=        `<p class="card-text">${sortingHat[i].house}</p>`
        domString +=        `<a onclick="expelStudentEvent()" id="${sortingHat[i].id}" href="#" class="expel">Expel</a>`
        domString +=        `</div>`
        domString +=    `</div>`
        domString +=    `</div>`
    }
    
    printToDom('studentCard', domString)
    
};



//pass in id of the card i'm clicking

//i want this function to delete 1 card when the button on said card is clicked

const expelStudentEvent = () => {
    let domString = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
        domString += ``
        } if(students.length = 0){}
        console.log(students)
    printToDom('studentCard', domString);
};


//this function takes my users input into the form and my hogwarts array into an array that gives each input an id

const sortInit = (e) => {

    const student = {
        id: studentId,
        name: names.value,
        house: hogwartsHouse[Math.floor(Math.random() * hogwartsHouse.length)],
    }
    students.push(student);
    console.log(students);
    studentId++;
    sortBuilder(students);
};

// const removeCard = () => {
//     let myCard = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
// }

//this function holds my event listeners

const events = () =>{
    document.getElementById('sort').addEventListener('click', sortInit)
    document.getElementById(e.target.id).addEventListener('click', expelStudentEvent)
}

//this function holds all of the previous functions

const init = () => {
    openForm();
    sortBuilder(students);
    events(students)
    expelStudentEvent(e)
    sortInit(expelStudentEvent)
};

//this function executes all functions

init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="jumbo" class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Sorting Hat</h1>
        <p class="lead">Hello muggles, are you a big fan of Harry Potter? </p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>Well you are in luck. Now you will be able to use this website to try on the sorting hat and see which house you will be sorted into.</p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a id="initForm" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="openForm();" href="#" role="button">Lets Get It Started!</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      

<div id="form">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <h3 class="display-6">Enter First Year's Name</h3>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <label for="insertName" class="sr-only">name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="insertName" placeholder="Harry Potter">
      </div>
      <button id="sort" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Sort</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="studentCard"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--<script src="main.js"></script>-->
</body>
```

any suggestions or solution would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: Adding an example of the HTML might be useful but one thing I am noticing right away is that it appears you are using the same ID for multiple cards (`<div id="cardContainer">`). An id should only apply to a singular element on the page. You can use classes for multiple elements with the same name where you can step through them like an array

Comment: I've added my html for more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are assigning student.length = 0. Your if-statement should look like:

`if(students.length == 0){}`.

2. Your expelStudentEvent function deletes your cards, because it deletes everything based on the length of your cards.

Try something like this:

```
const sortBuilder = (sortingHat) => {

let domString = '';
for(let i = 0; i < sortingHat.length; i++){
    domString +=    `<div id="cardContainer">`
    domString +=    `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">`
    domString +=        `<div class="card-body">`
    domString +=        `<h5 class="cardTitle">${sortingHat[i].name}</h5>`
    domString +=        `<p class="card-text">${sortingHat[i].house}</p>`
    domString +=        `<a onclick="expelStudentEvent(${i})" id="${sortingHat[i].id}" href="#" class="expel">Expel</a>`
    domString +=        `</div>`
    domString +=    `</div>`
    domString +=    `</div>`
}

printToDom('studentCard', domString)

};

const expelStudentEvent = (index) => {
    students.splice(index,1);
    sortBuilder(students);
};
```

Comment: i've made the change, however the outcome is still the same. my button is still deleting all of the cards that have been populated instead of just one card. thank you for your comment

Comment: in fact doing this presents another problem where all the cards are being saved (not quite sure how..) and when i delete them and then add a new card it shows all the other cards that i've "expelled"

Comment: your cards are deleted because your delete function just runs over the whole students array and is nulling all dom elements. you need to just find the card based on the students id and splice it from the students array.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would i accomplish that? I'm not sure how to grab the id's of the cards. from how i understand my code i'm giving the cards an id that is equal to number generate for their spot in the array (please correct me if i'm wrong) how would i grab the id of said cards if that is true? would it look something like students.studentId?

Comment: wow thats amazing.. i guess i was over thinking it entirely. so if i understand this correctly. it didn't work because like you said, i'm deleting cards based on the length of my array. which is set to 0, if i splice it into the array at 1 it will create a blank domstring?

Comment: the problem was the for loop in your delete function, yes, it was always creating a blank domstring, because your amount of cards represents the length of your students array. if one card is deleted your function runs over all cards/students and generates blank strings. now you are just removing the one student from the array based on its position/index and building new cards from your sortBuilder.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and patience. I'll do a similar project and try to implement this on my own. much appreciated.